Polymorphisme: masked method signature
I have this compile error because of polymorphisme (i guess)

error: no matching function for call to ‘derived::print()’

:
#include <iostream>

class base{
    public:
    void print()
    {
        print("Hello from ");
    }
    private:
    virtual void print(const std::string & message)
    {
        std::cout << message << " base class !! \n";
    }
};

class derived: public base{
    private:
    void print(const std::string & message) override
    {
        std::cout << message << " derived class !! \n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    base b;
    b.print();
    derived d;
    d.print();
    return 0;
}

What is the best solution without renaming the method print neither duplicate it in the derived class ?

Can you change the print method in your base class and derivced class from "private" to "public"? So you can call it from outside, i.e. from your main method.

my real code is supposed to call the print method of several instances (mix of bases and derived class)

If you can make print protected rather than private, you can solve the issue with using base::print. Demo. This is probably a good idea in any case, so the override can call the base class' version.

yes, it is the best solution for me, thanks. can you convert the comment on answer ?

There is no renaming, no duplicate :)
int main()
{
    base b;
    b.print();
    derived d;
    d.base::print(); // or ((base&)d).print();
    return 0;
}


good proposal, but it means that i have to modify the caller :/.  In my real code i have a container of mixed derived and base class

The base class function can be accessed in the same way: base* b_ptr = new base(); base* d_ptr = new derived(); (*b_ptr).print(); (*d_ptr).print(); delete b_ptr; delete d_ptr; Or something else?

yes, with instances with pointers it certainly works.
